# Use of preposition in or of with decline

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> The decline of his moral values has caused a lot of pain to his parents.

What will come with decline in the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with "decline *of* moral values"  But "Decline in" is also possible.

Culturally the sentence is odd.  I can't imagine anyone saying this in the UK. We would be more concerned with his behaviour than his values.